# GetElementsByTagName in ComponentDidMount() returns undefined despite rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, clicktale

Right now I am attempting to create a function in the ComponentDidMount lifecycle method that will inject a script tag into the return statement. This script will be used to invoke [Clicktale](https://www.clicktale.com/). However, even after checking that the component has mounted and that the document state has reached 'complete', when I try to find the script tag it keeps returning undefined. Because of this I am unable to add attributes to the script tag that will invoke Clicktale. Typically with Clicktale you just need to add the script at the bottom of the body, but for the project I am working on I need to use React.

I know that when using the method getElementsByTagName in React it should return an array of elements that have that tag name. But when console logging 
`document.getElementsByTagName('script')`
I just receive
`HTMLCollection {}`
Which I assume means it's empty since logging `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]`
returns undefined.

This is the main component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Clicktale extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.clickTaleTagInjected) {
        const clickTaleTagInjected = true;
        function injectTag() {
          const ns = document.createElementNS;
          const a = ns ? ns.call(document, 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'script') : document.createElement('script');
          const s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          a.async = true;
          a.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
          a.type = 'text/javascript';
          a.src = 'specific clicktale cdn url I am using here';
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s);
        }
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
          injectTag();
        } else {
          window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            setTimeout(injectTag, 0);
          });
        }
      }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Clicktale;
```

And this is the parent component (I don't think this should be interfering?):

```
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import Clicktale from './Clicktale';


export const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Helmet
      link={[
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'using private link here',
        },
      ]}
    />
    <Clicktale />
  </div>
);

export default Parent;
```

The specific error I receive is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
```

this refers to the line with

```
s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s)
```

Ultimately, I was trying to figure out why it cannot find the script tag after it has been injected. I'm also wondering if I should have something other than div tags in the return? I figured the component would be able to inject a script tag in there with no issues, but this is...not the case.

Thank you for any pointers :)

Comment: Why can't you just add the script tag in your html file? This is probably a timing issue because the load of clicktale is async

Comment: @JohnRuddell At the moment I have just have this parent component and child component and no file that's strictly html. A straight up html file would be the easiest route, but unfortunately this project I'm helping out with is supposed to be structured this way :/

Comment: Wait, does this particular application not have an html file at all? why would someone do that? you can have issues if there is no document type definition. You should push to get a html file added. You can also put a unique id on the script to grab that one element rather than use get by tag name.